# How to change my apostrophecms password while signed in

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In the [apostrophe-login](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-login/) module there is the option *passwordReset* to activate a "forgot password" feature, allowing users to receive a link via email to reset their passwords. However, I would also like to enable users to change their password without involving email just by providing their old password again while signed in. There seems to be an option for that as well, named *resetKnownPassword*. However, I can't figure out how to activate/use this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out my problem myself. I had overridden *addAdminBarItems* in *apostrophe-login*'s constructor to avoid adding the logout link to the admin bar. Which also overrides the code to add the change password link. After removing that, a button shows up in the admin bar which opens a layer with the password change form, and all is well.